# Dynamically add tiles into jsp page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, struts, tiles

I am new with struts-1 and tiles. The problem I am having is dynamically adding tiles to a table. Can anyone point me to the right direction

myTestTable.jsp
//jsp page with table and script to add new row

```
<table id="testing" style="padding-top: 10px">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Student Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addCF">Add</a></td>
          <td>
            <tiles:insert definition=".textInput">
              <tiles:put name="property" value="parameter[01]"/>
              <tiles:put name="width" value="75"/>                               
            </tiles:insert>
           </td>
         <tr>
       </tbody>
</table>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".addCF").click(function(){
    $("#testing").append('<tr><td>
        <tiles:insert definition=".textInput">
          <tiles:put name="property" value="parameter[02]"/>
          <tiles:put name="width" value="75"/> 
        </tiles:insert></td> </tr>');
});
});


</script>
```

Would this be the correct way to go about adding another row of tiles? or is there a better way to go about this? it would have to be every time a user clicks the add button so might be 1 or 20.